# Storing android checkbox state in SQL database

Tags: java, php, android, sql, checkbox

I am creating an app that will allow users to register with their names, ages, etc. I am storing all of this information in a User class, which looks like this.

```
public class User {

String name, username, password, phoneNumber;
int age;

//constructor
public User(String _name, String _username, String _password, String _phoneNumber, int _age){
    name = _name;
    username = _username;
    password = _password;
    phoneNumber = _phoneNumber;
    age = _age;
}
}
```

I am sending that data to a PHP script to store in an SQL database. That code is as follows:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneNumber", user.phoneNumber));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now I want to create about 10 checkboxes whose state (checked vs unchecked) I can store. I know that I could create a bunch of boolean values as part of the User class, but that seems cumbersome and bad practice. My question is, therefore, how best to store the CheckBox data in the SQL database?

For reference, the PHP script is as follows:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "is_clients");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$phoneNumber = $_POST["phoneNumber"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username, password, phoneNumber) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sisss", $name, $age, $username, $password, $phoneNumber);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: How about giving a random value lets say 1 if its checked and sending it as POST, on php if POST is set save it as checked if POST not set then save it as not checked

Comment: @mrahmat My question is how I would implement that from within the Java. Should I create an entirely new class called CheckBoxData, for example? and then how would I send that to the PHP script? Would I use a separate PHP script? or would I modify my current script to accept the checkbox states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an array to PHP, each element in the array can be a check box value.
In PHP you can do that by using a variable with brackets like checkBoxesArr[] so you can use the  same variable, and every occurrence would be another element in the array.

So, in Java (checkBoxXXXValue can be a binary or boolean):

```
dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkBoxArr[]", checkBoxOneValue));
dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkBoxArr[]", checkBoxTwoValue));
dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkBoxArr[]", checkBoxThreeValue));
```

PHP:

```
$checkBoxArr = $_POST['checkBoxArr'];
print_r($checkBoxArr);
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: This helps a lot. So would I need to create a POST variable for each item in the array?

Comment: Yes, post variable for each element with the same name and don't forget the brackets. 
Alternatively you could concatenate all values to a single string and send it to the PHP which would then explode/split them back to the array, but using the native array support in $_POST does most of the work for you.